# How to make a protected singleton method

Tags: ruby, protected

How can I make the following method `some_protected` protected or private? It should be implemented without inheritance.

```
module Sample
  def self.some_public
    some_protected
  end

  protected

  def self.some_protected
    puts 'Bingo!'
  end
end

Sample::some_public     # Bingo!
Sample::some_protected  # Bingo! (but expected an error that method is not accessible)
```

Comment: Why would you want to have this method _protected_? Does not make much sense to me when working with class methods.

Comment: Maybe. What exactly you think could be wrong?

Comment: What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want to hide some functionality from public access. Just to open allow to a couple functions instead ten ones. I wouldn't keep whole code of a function in the same function if it's not small. It should be refactored to small one. And these small one should not be accessible.

Comment: Why not private then? 

use "private_class_method" for this.

Comment: Why not protected? :) I dislike private ones. They cannot be inherited/used externally. It's pretty rare case to use private visibility.

Comment: I use protected visibility, when I have instances (for equality comparators or so) but not for class methods.
Can you show how you would access the protected class methods from anything else but Sample?

If it were a use case, then ruby would probably provide "protected_class_method", as it does for "private_class_method" instead of having you do some singleton class magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working within the singleton class is probably the easiest.

```
module Sample; end

class <<Sample
  def some_public
    some_protected
  end
  protected def some_protected
    puts 'Bingo!'
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, seem that's what I need.